# How to fix 'Android Webview loading error page frequently'?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

My Webview app loads error page(.html) as soon as it detects Error(No Internet Connection). It happens immediately when there is no connection or weak network.

My code is as follows

MainActivity.xml

```
package *.*.*;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebResourceError;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import *.*.*.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView MyWebView;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipe;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_menu);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.nav_home:
                        MyWebView.loadUrl("http://***.com");
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_allproducts:
                        MyWebView.loadUrl("http://***.com/index.php?route=product/allproduct&limit=50");
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_newarrivals:
                        MyWebView.loadUrl("http://***.com/index.php?route=product/latest");
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_login:
                        MyWebView.loadUrl("http://***.com/index.php?route=account/login");
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_myaccount:
                        MyWebView.loadUrl("http://***.com/index.php?route=account/account");
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_mywishlist:
                        MyWebView.loadUrl("http://***.com/index.php?route=account/wishlist");
                        break;
                }
                DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
            }
        });

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            NotificationChannel mChannel =
                    new NotificationChannel(Constants.CHANNEL_ID, Constants.CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            mChannel.setDescription(Constants.CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION);
            mChannel.enableLights(true);
            mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            mChannel.enableVibration(true);

            mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100,200,300,400,500,400,300,200,400});

            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }

        MyWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                    LoadWeb(MyWebView.getUrl());
            }
        });

        LoadWeb("http://***.com");
    }

    public void LoadWeb (String url){

        WebSettings webSettings = MyWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        MyWebView.loadUrl(url);
        swipe.setRefreshing(true);
        MyWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                MyWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
            }


            //For versions < Android M (API 23).
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                MyWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
            }


            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                //Hide the swipeRefreshLayout
                swipe.setRefreshing(false);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(MyWebView.canGoBack()) {
            MyWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

I want it to stay on the existing page when it detects the error and display the error page when only user clicks any link in Webview.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to show blank screen, when receive an error

```
MyWebView.loadUrl(about:blank);
```

in `onReceivedError`.